# Accidentally deleted the email linked to github

Tags: github

I accidentally deleted the email linked to github.
So, the commit grass that was linked to my email was deleted.
I registered my deleted email again, but it didn't come back.

How can I revert my commit grass?

Comment: What do you mean with "commit grass"? If you mean your contribution activity, then associating the email address under https://github.com/settings/emails should be sufficient (though presumably it might take a while for GitHub to index stuff).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes i mean contribution activity in github profile :) i think it will takes some time too. i will wait. thanks your comment.